# accessibility issue for tablist role

Tags: c#, html, keyboard, screen-readers

```
<uib-tabset role="tablist"  >
    <uib-tab  ><uib-tab-heading>
        <div role="tab">One
    </div></uib-tab-heading>
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab  ><uib-tab-heading>
        <div role="tab">Two
    </div></uib-tab-heading>
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab  ><uib-tab-heading>
        <div role="tab">Three
    </div></uib-tab-heading>
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

getting accessibility bug as Required ARIA parent role not present: tablist and Required ARIA child role not present: tab

Answer (score 0):

**How to add missing parent roles**

Option 1: Place the child elements within the parent in the DOM

Option 2: Associate the child roles with the parent role using aria-owns

[SOURCE](https://web.dev/aria-required-parent/)

[Accessibility Insights](https://accessibilityinsights.io/info-examples/web/aria-required-parent/)

Consider using [LIGHTHOUSE](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse) to audit ARIA compliance.

Comment: for dynamically how to use ,

Comment: <body>
 <uib-tabset role="tablist"  >
  <uib tab ng-repeat="tabItem in TabGroup">
   <uib-tab-heading>
    <div role="tab">
     <span>{{tabItem.tabGroupName}}</span>
    </div>
   </uib-tab-heading>
  </uib-tab-heading>
 </uib-tabset>
    </body>

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your solution, can you please give me solution if tab are created dynamically then how do resolve accessibility issue

```
<body>
<uib-tabset role="tablist"  >
    <uib tab ng-repeat="tabItem in TabGroup">
        <uib-tab-heading>
            <div role="tab">
                <span>{{tabItem.tabGroupName}}</span>
            </div>
        </uib-tab-heading>
    </uib-tab-heading>
</uib-tabset>
</body>
```